# How to exclude brackets at the end of the Url

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am new to regex, so any help is really appreciated.
I have an expression to identify a URL :
`(http[^'\"]+)`

Unfortunately on some URLs, I get additional square brackets at the end
For instance "http://example.com]]"

As the result want to receive "http://example.com"

How do I get rid of those brackets with the help of the regex I wrote above?

Comment: Better try this regex `^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$` and also, what language r u using?

Comment: @GhostOps, i hope there is an easier solution.

Comment: in which language r u using this regex? the above one is a any valid url checker

Comment: @GhostOps something similar to javascript

Comment: I'll note that this conversation - so far - has been limited to HTTP, HTTPS and FTP. I hope that's enough for the original questioner.

Comment: Are you working with json, xml or something similar to that? cuz the `]]` after `com/` is still a valid url

Comment: @GhostOps, i dont....i just wanted a regex to get rid of the square brackets at the end of the url. it could be like http://www.example.ra/coin]] and i wanted to get only http://www.example.ra/coin

Comment: Try `https?:\/\/(www.)?.+(?<!\])`

Comment: If you add [ and ] in your square bracket in pattern this will work: [`(http[^'"\[\]]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/mKDcMK/1) **BUT** this is not a good way to identify a URL.

Comment: @Alireza yeah because some urls use [ and ] after the top level domain...

Comment: @GhostOps Actually not because of this, this pattern will match a non-url string too. something like: "http hey how are you?" will match, so this pattern basically is not a good pattern to identify URLs.

Comment: @Alireza how about `https?:\/\/(www.)?.+(?<!\])` (which was my answer mentioned in comments)

Comment: @GhostOps , can you please explain it briefly?

Comment: @GhostOps You need to escape dot after www, and if in the end of URL is some more characters this pattern will fail, something like this: "http://example.com]]a"

Comment: @Alireza point noted down.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you actually have is called a negated character class, so just add characters that should not be matched. In addition, there's not really a need for a capturing group. That said, you could use

```
http[^'"\]\[]+
#       ^^^^
```

Note that this will exclude square brackets *anywhere* in your possible url not just at the end. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/geOUbI/1).

Answer (score 1):

Stop the match between a word and nonword character:

```
(http[^'"]+)\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/v4EVQf/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"]+                   any character except: ''', '"' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```